# Get column value in the scriptdb query statement in google apps script with quotes e.g. "Cust Name"

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the value of a column from a `ScriptDb` database for a column called "Cust Name" - if it was CustName or similar I could do the following:

```
while(result.hasnext()){ 

  res = result.next();
  var CustName = res.CustName;

}
```

How you I get the value if the column is called "Cust Name"?

Comment: Although the space character is allowed in a ScriptDb object property, you should avoid anything that requires square-brackets to access. Take a look at the "note" [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb#saving_data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing it as a with dot notation, you could try this:

```
while(result.hasnext()){ 

  res = result.next();
  var CustName = res["Cust Name"];

}
```

I tested this using a spreadsheet (since that is one way you can get a property with a space loaded), and it returned the correct value for a column with a space.